# How to start locahost or entry in localhost using browser in Docker - Magento 2

Tags: docker, magento, localhost

i just start using docker and i install a docker for use Magento 2, this is the github repo: GitHub - markshust/docker-magento: Mark Shust’s Docker Configuration for Magento, the docker install correctly but when i just try to open in my browser the link https://magento2.test i just get error like when the web page do not exist, can you guide me of how to entry in the localhost?

Comment: github repo: https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento

Answer (score 0):

I know some time has passed since this post, however I would recommend re-installing it using the fully automated one-line setup as a lot has changed since your post: https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento#automated-setup-new-project

There is also a full screencast course (which is free) which can help walk you through setting up a Magento 2 development environment with Docker https://m.academy/p/setup-magento-2-development-environment-docker

Without a specific diagnosis, it's hard to recommend anything else at the moment except to try to do a re-install and report back if you have any further issues.

Hope this helps!